# SendOnBehalfOf in DocuSign Java SDK

Tags: docusignapi

In java, How can i use SendOnBehalfOf using docusign java sdk as I need to send envelope on behalf of another user.

I am using : docusign-esign-java-2.0.1.jar

Comment: Added below 
apiClient.addDefaultHeader("X-DocuSign-Act-As-User", "");
and  apiClient.addDefaultHeader("Authorization:bearer", "");
can send on behalf of another user. Is there any other way?

Answer (score 2):

I added the below value to the headers and was able to send on behalf of another user:

```
apiClient.addDefaultHeader("Authorization:bearer", "token");
apiClient.addDefaultHeader("X-DocuSign-Act-As-User", emailId);
```

To fetch the token need to use the url below and pass the token in the above header

https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/oauth2/token

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a bit old, but I just came across it and was able to figure out a different way to accomplish it.  I simply added the SendOnBehalfOf parameter as part of the authentication header.

So I build the authentication header to look like this:

```
String authHeader = "{ "
                + "\"Username\": \"myemail@example.com\", "
                + "\"Password\": \"MyR4ndomPa$$wOrd\", "
                + "\"IntegratorKey\": \"xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx\", "
                + "\"SendOnBehalfOf\": \"someotheruser@example.com\" "
                + "}";
ApiClient apiClient = new ApiClient("https://demo.docusign.net/restapi");
apiClient.addDefaultHeader("X-DocuSign-Authentication", authHeader);
```